# Heroku: unable to resolve DNS for server

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting, cname, ovh

I bought a `myapp.app` domain with OVH. I've also bought a Heroku hobby dyno in order to have a secure subdomain for my api (`https://www.server.myapp.app` instead of `https://www.myapp.heroku.app`).

In Heroku's dashboard/settings, I've added the domain `server.myapp.app` and copied the generated DNS target provided by Heroku. It looks like: `hello-world-5fghjofz765h.herokudns.com`.

Then, I added a CNAME record in OVH's DNS zone panel. The name is `server.myapp.app`. But when validating the entry, I notice the generated domain has an additional `.` in the end: `server.myapp.app.`

Is it normal? Should I enter the same name with a final dot in Heroku too?

Next. I added a CNAME record in my DNS zone panel.

When copy/pasting the DNS target in ovh, ovh claims that this is a relative notation that will point to `hello-world-5fghjofz765h.herokudns.com.myapp.app.`.

They say I can add a `.` in the end to make this notation absolute and point to `hello-world-5fghjofz765h.herokudns.com.`. I don't understand what it means.

In any case, the DNS target is not strictly equal to the DNS provided by Heroku. There is either an additional `.` or a `myapp.app.` in the end of the url.

Anyway, I've tried both options. In each case, Heroku says they're `unable to resolve DNS for server`. The final error is: `1 domain failed validation`.

How to fix this? I'm paying for a dyno I can't even access.

EDIT:
The ovh DNS Zone. I own the domain `www.myapp.app` (`myapp` is a random name for this example, and is hidden by a black rectangle on the images below).

[image]

The heroku subdomain settings:
[image]

Comment: This answer will help you understand the trailing dot in DNS resource records: https://serverfault.com/a/18126/437769

Comment: Thanks John! So absolute notation is the way to go. However, 12 hours later, Heroku still can't find the DNS. Should I write www.server.myapp.app or server.myapp.app in Heroku's domain name input? Maybe the error comes from here? Indeed, after entering server.myapp.app, Heroku says the server is available at the address our app can be found at http://server.myapp.app, which sounds weird. It should be https://www.server.myapp.app, right?

Comment: Your question contains a lot of detail that is not necessary. All I need to see is the DNS resource records that you configured and what domain names you want to work.

Comment: Sorry for all the unnecessary details. I've updated the original post with two screenshots: one with the CNAME entered in OVH, and another with the Heroku settings. I need to have the client on `https://www.myapp.app` (it's already working on Netlify), and a server on `https://www.server.myapp.app` on Heroku, so I can send sameSite cookies. Please let me know if you need any additional information.  Thanks a lot for your help, I do highly appreciate it.

Comment: Do not use pictures. Create a list of DNS resource records as TEXT in your question. However, without being able to see the actual names, I cannot test your records. Use an Internet site such as mxtoolbox to test your DNS resource records.